# Solve a differential equation $(x+y^2)dy=ydx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Find a solution to the differential equation:
>   $$
> (x+y^2)dy=ydx
> $$

I tried to express $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ to see what type of the differential equation it is.
$$
y'=\frac{y}{x+y^2}
$$
It became clear that I can't represent $y'$ as a product of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.
And it doesn't seem to be homogeneous. Then I checked whether it is exact:
$$
(x+y^2)'_x=1\ne(-y)'_y=-1
$$
And it tuned out that the differential equation is not exact either.

I do not know all the types of differential equations yet, so I would appreciate if someone showed me how to solve this one.

Comment: Use x=vy and try to solelve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ydx-xdy=y^2dy\Rightarrow \frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}=dy$$

$$\Longrightarrow d\bigg(\frac{x}{y}\bigg)=d(y)$$

Integrate both Side, Getting $$\frac{x}{y}=y+C\Rightarrow x=y^2+Cy$$

Comment: It looks very neat, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+y^2)dy=ydx$$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$x'-\dfrac x y=y$$
It's a linear first DE use any method you know to solve it. You can also use
$$\left (\frac f g \right )'=\frac {f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$
$$\implies \left (\frac xy \right )'=1$$
$$ \left (\frac xy \right )=y+C$$
$$x(y)=y^2+Cy$$

Answer (score 1):

We solve $df=0$ with the Ansatz $f_x=x^ay^{b+1},\,f_y=-x^{a+1}y^b-x^ay^{b+2}$ so$$\begin{align}0&=(f_x)_y-(f_y)_x\\&=(b+1)x^ay^b+(a+1)x^ay^b+ax^{a-1}y^{b+2}\\\implies (a+b+2,\,a)&=0\\\implies(a,\,b)&=(0,\,-2)\\\implies df&=dx/y-(x/y^2+1)dy\\\implies f&=x/y+y+C.\end{align}$$Since $df=0$, we can set $f=0$, viz. $x=-y^2-Cy$.